# Files unexpectedly ignored in git repo - need this behavior to stop

Tags: git, visual-studio-2012, git-gui

After a manual update of a directory, a few files are shown as ignored in my development repo. These files or file types are not listed as 'to be ignored'. How can I stop them from being ignored?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are saying is that there are some files that are unexpectedly ignored and you'd like that to stop.

Ignores can be setup in a few places.  From a global level, `core.excludesfile` can be set to point to a file containing a list of ignores.  The default points to `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/ignore` or `$HOME/.config/git/ignore`, if `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is not set--and it's probably not if you're running Windows.  `core.excludesfiles` can also be set at a repository-level, and ignores can also be set in `.git/info/exclude`.  You should see the pattern you want in one of those locations and remove it.

Comment: I checked the git dir, there is no such configuration. I have one file .gitIgnore at the same level of the git folder.

Comment: What does `git config --get core.excludesfile` say?  Also, what is the contents of your `.gitignore` file, and what is the filename that is being hidden?  BTW, I'm not sure if it was a simple typo, but you wrote `.gitIgnore` (capital I in ignore), and it should be `.gitignore` (all lowercase).

Comment: gitognore_global says: #ignore thumbnails created by windows
Thumbs.db
#Ignore files build by Visual Studio
*.obj
*.exe
*.pdb
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.cache
*.ilk
*.log
*.dll
*.lib
*.sbr

Comment: What filename are you having an issue with?

Comment: Sequencer.cs, there are several other files in that dir showing locked. and this is the only file showing ignored.

Comment: Hmm... I'm not familiar with Visual Studio's integration.  What do you mean "locked"?  Git doesn't "lock" files.  What does the Git command line say (`git status`)?  You should probably update your question with that information, as it won't be readable in a comment.

Comment: Sorry the term locked can be confusing. Unchanged files show a lock in VS, edited files show a check mark.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36566/discussion-between-xdrone-and-jszakmeister)